# print long string in one line of the conosole

Tags: python, printing, console

I want to print a long string in just one console line without wrapping, for example I want
`print('A'*500)` to produce a long line of 'A's where I can scroll, like

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

the normal console output is something like

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

how can I get my desired output?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Python but with the console. Try output into a file via `python yourscript > somefile.txt` to see that the output of your script is only one line! So configuring the console window may help solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a console specification, it is necessary to specify the number of lines to be displayed on the software side.
The method differs depending on Windows and MAC.

Comment: is there a way to set that in python, with the os module perhaps?

Comment: *on the software side* -- this is a bit vague, right? 1) by a Python switch? 2) in the script? 3) in the OS? 4) ... etc?

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to off text wrapping.
So you have to just work the way it is

Comment: * to off* ->  *to **switch** off*?